# How can you modify and edit image colors on mouse hover?

Tags: html, css, image-processing, mouseover, processing.js

See this visualization here where the color of the image is changed when you mouse hover the image:
http://thebandcalledboy.com/

I'm trying to replicate the same behavior. Any clues?

Comment: I think it's with svg, and javascript.  look into how a TD game does an explosion radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ":hover" pseudo-class to give a different style to an element that is hovered over. For example, if you have an element like this:

```
  <div class="my-element">Content</div>
```

You can style the element differently when it is hovered over:

```
   .my-element {
     background: green;
   }
   .my-element:hover {
     background: red;
   }
```

The code above gives the element a red background on hover but a green background otherwise. You can use a similar technique (albeit with different CSS properties) to either select two different background images or to reuse the same image but apply a different color mask on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome, right on the image->inspect element. What you will get is this:

```
HTML:

</div>
        <img src="sites/all/themes/boy/images/boy_logo.png" class="logo" alt=""/>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
element.style {
}
thebandcalledboy.com/media="all"
#center .black {
width: 96%;
height: 97%;
margin: 2%;
background: #000;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
display: block;
}
Inherited from body
Style Attribute {
font-size: 7.9375px;
}
thebandcalledboy.com/media="all"
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
font-family:'PerpetuaRegular',arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
}
Inherited from html.js.textshadow.fontface.audio.svg
thebandcalledboy.com/media="all"
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: 'PerpetuaRegular',arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Similarly see

> computed 
>   and 
>   event listeners there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would draw the colors onto a off screen PGraphic object and use something like the PImage blend function to mask it onto the template of the boy's face.